# ListView scroll to bottom as all binding data loaded

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have a **ListView** in my xaml which is binded to **ReadOnlyObservableCollection** which contains items.

How can I scroll to the bottom of the **ListView** when all the binded list loaded?

I've tried to use the  **myList.ScrollToBottom()** function as I add the data to mylist (on ViewModel) - the scroll isn't visible, it doesn't scroll till the end of the list.

I've tried to subscribe to Lists **Loaded** , **CollectionChanged** and **ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged** events, and then to scroll to the bottom didn't helped either.

If I subscribe to my event (on ViewModel) which I fire as I set the data to my List, and then I call ScrollToBottom function with a slight delay - the scroll is perfect, so I guess it's timing issue...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Windows Phone or WPF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
myList.ScrollIntoView(myList.Items[myList.Items.Count - 1])
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! I've change it a bit to: myList.ScrollIntoView(myList.Items[myList.Items.Count - 1]);

Comment: @PavelDurov sorry.I typed it fast so missed the Items

Comment: No need to sorry. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing this if you have a ViewModel?  The ViewModel wouldn't know what control you're talking about.  So how can your ViewModel reference "myList"?

I'm also trying to get the ListView to scroll to the last item when the collection is updated, but none of the ScrollTo features are available in in the XAML: THere's no way to bind to them.  These seem to all be METHODS, meaning you can't do property MVVM with it.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The ViewModel exposes the collection as a property, he isn't aware of the listView control. listView control binds its ItemSource to that property. I'm not quite sure about your question though - what do you mean?